# Replace Parse-Server example (MyFirstApp) app with new app

Tags: parse-server

I've installed and have working Parse-Server locally and have Parse Dashboard working also.  Along with the install came MyFirstApp.  So, Parse-Server does not support multiple apps per discussions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773227/create-new-app-on-own-parse-server

[How to create app with Parse-Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486877/how-to-create-app-with-parse-server)

[Create new apps using dashboard](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/188)

But, it's really unclear how to delete MyFirstApp and create a new app.  Any pointers greatly appreciated.  I get how to point Parse Dashboard at the new app. My problem is how to delete one and create a new app.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't you create an app when you first setup Parse Server? It sounds like you named that "MyFirstApp". Otherwise, there is likely a REST endpoint to delete an app

Comment: It appears to me that the MyFirstApp comes as part of the install.  According to Github instructions, you install MongoDB, then Parse-Server.  Next step is to run it and then the very next step is to save your first object to the GameScore class.

Comment: Here's the curl command to add to the GameScore class:

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore